# Mongo update array of string into array of embedded objects

Tags: mongodb

I have some data stored in my `MongoDB`. The "tags" fields is actually an array of `Strings`, but we have to update our model to store more data with those tags

Current model document

```
{
    "id" : "59e4aefd74f12800019ba565",
    "title" : "This is a title",
    "tags" : [ 
        "59b02e6f6b28ce0001f8c0a8", 
        "59b031886b28ce0001f8c0af", 
        "59ba8c1a5047570001a3c078"
    ]
}
```

Desired model after update

```
{
    "id" : "59e4aefd74f12800019ba565",
    "title" : "This is a title",
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "5a82ff1d889a15000103b115",
            "internalName" : "Día Mundial de la Television"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "59ba8c1a5047570001a3c078",
            "internalName" : "menu"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "5a26ac73d0fc2e00017f286e",
            "internalName" : "oid_asdf_asd"
        }
    ],


}
```

Now tags is a embedded object (forget about internalName field). How can I update the tag field without losing those data? I've tried with $rename, but it doesn't work well with arrays

```
db.test.update({}, {$rename: {'tags': 'tags2.id'}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the concepts from this [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field/37280419#37280419), you could create a cursor from an aggregate operation that transforms the tags arrays by using the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** operator, iterate the cursor and update your collection using **[`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)**.
The aggregate operation follows:

```
var cursor = db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "tags": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$tags",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": { 
                        "id": "$$el",
                        "internalName": { "$literal": "temp string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

And running the bulk update:

```
var bulkUpdateOps = [];

cursor.forEach(doc => {
    const { _id, tags } = doc;
    bulkUpdateOps.push({
        "updateOne": {
           "filter": { _id },
           "update": { "$set": { tags } },
           "upsert": true
        }
    });

    if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 1000) {
        db.test.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);  
        bulkUpdateOps = [];                 
    }
}); 

if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) {
    db.test.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm testing it right now but it doesn't seems to works. (My bad probably). I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @dragonalvaro There was a typo in the code which I removed, try again

Comment: Now it worked! Thank you very much. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Just one more correction, move the first if condition check into the forEach loop for it to work correctly i.e. execute the bulk updfate in batches of 1000. I have updated my answer to reflect this.